# DISCORD: My Discord self bot takes too much time to load

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I coded a Discord self bot that sends a picture that acts like a global emote without nitro.

Example:

> me: !ok
>
> me(bot): ok.png

But when I edit my code and add more pictures and stuff and I load it again (By doing "mybot.py" in cmd) it takes around 5 minutes to finally print "Self bot working." in the cmd window... what is the problem? I don't think it's a problem with my code because it's working overall. I'm using python 3.6 and windows.

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("nonitro Loaded.\n")
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        if(message.content.startswith("!ok")):
            emo = "./img/ok.png"
            async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel,limit=1):
                await client.delete_message(msg)
                await client.send_file(message.channel, emo)
                
    if message.author == client.user:
        if(message.content.startswith("!xd")):
            emo = "./img/xd.png"
            async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel,limit=1):
                await client.delete_message(msg)
                await client.send_file(message.channel, emo)
                
    if message.author == client.user:
        if(message.content.startswith("!coffee")):
            emo = "./img/coffee.png"
            async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel,limit=1):
                await client.delete_message(msg)
                await client.send_file(message.channel, emo)
                                
    if message.author == client.user:
        if(message.content.startswith("!thonk")):
            emo = "./img/thonk.png"
            async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel,limit=1):
                await client.delete_message(msg)
                await client.send_file(message.channel, emo)
                                
    if message.author == client.user:
        if(message.content.startswith("!like")):
            emo = "./img/like.png"
            async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel,limit=1):
                await client.delete_message(msg)
                await client.send_file(message.channel, emo)
                                
    if message.author == client.user:
        if(message.content.startswith("!kek")):
            emo = "./img/kek.png"
            async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel,limit=1):
                await client.delete_message(msg)
                await client.send_file(message.channel, emo)
                                                
    if message.author == client.user:
        if(message.content.startswith("!bobross")):
            emo = "./img/bobross.png"
            async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel,limit=1):
                await client.delete_message(msg)
                await client.send_file(message.channel, emo)
                                                
    if message.author == client.user:
        if(message.content.startswith("!likethis")):
            emo = "./img/likethis.png"
            async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel,limit=1):
                await client.delete_message(msg)
                await client.send_file(message.channel, emo)

client.run("my token", bot=False)
```

Comment: Alright I will add in the code!

Comment: Please post all code as formatted text in the body of your question.  Your linked page could disappear suddenly, or be blocked at peoples workplaces.

Comment: Why are you passing `bot=False` to `run`?  Self bots are against the Discord terms of service, and they're pretty good at detecting them.  It's very possible that they've limited your connection in some way.  I would recommend switching to a regular token setup, and seeing if that improve the performance.

Comment: No, you don't understand my problem. it's not that the imgs take time to load or something... Running the python file in cmd takes so much to print that it's ready and working...

Comment: and also, the whole point of this is that it's a self bot...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pull logs from the chat in order to delete that one message, you can just do

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == "your id" and "!ok" == message.content:
        await client.delete_message(message)
        await client.send_file(message.channel,"path/to/file")
        return

client.run("token",bot=False)
```

Which will send message only if the content of the message is !ok and if its your id thats saying !ok